# Using discord.js, how would I check if a user has sent a message two times in a row?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

For a specific channel in my server, I want to make it so that a user can't send two messages in a row.
Here's the code I got so far:

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if(message.guild.id != '123478291364192834') return;
  if(message.channel.id != '432874912364123984') return;
  let messageauthor = ''
  message.channel.messages.fetch({limit:2}).then(messages=>{
    messages
    .forEach(message=>{
       messageauthor = message.author.id
    })
  })
  if(messageauthor == message.author.id){
      message.delete()
  }
})
```

The idea was that it'd fetch two messages in a channel and if the message author of the second message is fetched is the same as the message author, it'd delete the message. But it doesn't do that, does anyone know why or have any solutions to the problem?

Comment: Do you got any errors ? 

Had you tried adding a `console.log("Test");` above the message.delete() just to make it's going to be executed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code as-is.

### Problem

First of all, you're checking if `messageauthor` is equal to `message.author.id` *outside* of your `.then()`. The code inside a `.then()` has its execution delayed because it executes asynchronously. In other words, it takes some time to fetch the messages in the channel, which is why you can only access `messages` in your `.then()`. Because the contents of your `.then()` execute *after* the rest of your code, including the code that proceeds it, you are checking if `messageauthor` is equal to `message.author.id` *before* the value of `messageauthor` is even set. Your `if` statement will always be checking if the empty string `''` is equal to the ID of the message's author, which is always `false`, so the message will never be deleted.

Second, inside your `.then()` you are looping through the two messages you've fetched and are setting `messageauthor` to the ID of the message's author. But since you're doing this twice, since you fetched two total messages, that means that `messageauthor` is only set to the author ID of the second message. So why loop through both messages, when you can just immediately grab the author ID from the last message?

Finally, you're only checking if the author of the second message matches the ID of the current message's author. How that behaves depends on whether or not the current message is fetched along with the last message. If the current message is included in `messages`, then the second message literally *is* the current message, so that will delete every single message that anyone ever sends. If the current message isn't included in `messages`, then why are you fetching two messages with your `.fetch()`? From your question, it seems you do not want people to send two messages in a row. That would mean you only have to fetch 1 previous message and use just the message you fetched in your comparison. I will attempt to account for both of these possibilities below with two separate answers, as I am not sure whether the current message will be included.

### Solution

Here's how I would suggest you revise your code, assuming the current message *is* included in the fetched messages (I'm assuming this will not be the case):

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if(message.guild.id != '123478291364192834') return;
  if(message.channel.id != '432874912364123984') return;

  message.channel.messages.fetch({limit:2}).then(messages=>{
    let firstauthor = messages.first().author.id;        

    if(firstauthor == message.author.id){
      console.log("Deleting message because 2 messages in a row were sent");
      message.delete();
    }
  });
})
```

Here's what I would do if this current message is not included in the fetched messages (which I assume will be the case, so this *should* work properly):

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if(message.guild.id != '123478291364192834') return;
  if(message.channel.id != '432874912364123984') return;

  message.channel.messages.fetch({limit:1}).then(msg=>{
    let firstauthor = msg.author.id;        

    if(firstauthor == message.author.id){
      console.log("Deleting message because 2 messages in a row were sent");
      message.delete();
    }
  });
});
```

In both of these fixes, what I've done is first and foremost I've moved the `if` statement into the end of the `.then()`. This ensures that the condition is only checked after the messages have been fetched. Second, I removed the `forEach` loop and replaced it with simple references to the first, or only, item in the fetched message collection. Third, I made sure it was the first message, and not the second message, that would have its author's ID compared to the current message author's ID. And finally, I added a simple `console.log` to help you debug the issue. If the `console.log` never occurs but you know it is supposed to, that means something is wrong in the code.

Feel free to try either solution, or both, out and find which one works for you. I have not tested either thoroughly, so if you find an issue let me know and I will fix it. This should give you a general idea of what the issue is in your code nevertheless, so you should hopefully be able to fix the issue on your own even if these solutions do not work. I am guessing the second of the above solutions will work best.